# Run tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase using asyncio event loop

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, tornado, python-asyncio

I have an asyncio based class which I want to unit test. Using `tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase` this works quite well and easily. However, one specific method of my class uses `asyncio.ensure_future` to schedule execution of another method. This never finishes in the `AsyncTestCase`, because the default test runner uses the tornado `KQueueIOLoop` event loop, not an asyncio event loop.

```
class TestSubject:
    def foo(self):
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.bar())

    async def bar(self):
        pass
```

```
class TestSubjectTest(AsyncTestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        t = TestSubject()
        # here be somewhat involved setup with MagicMock and self.stop
        t.foo()
        self.wait()
```

```
$ python -m tornado.testing baz.testsubject_test
...
[E 160627 17:48:22 testing:731] FAIL
[E 160627 17:48:22 base_events:1090] Task was destroyed but it is pending!
    task: <Task pending coro=<TestSubject.bar() running at ...>>
.../asyncio/base_events.py:362: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TestSubject.bar' was never awaited
```

How can I use a different event loop to run the tests on to ensure my task will actually be executed? Alternatively, how can I make my implementation event loop-independent and cross-compatible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out to be simple enough...

```
class TestSubjectTest(AsyncTestCase):
    def get_new_ioloop(self):  # override this method
        return tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop()
```

I was trying this before, but directly returned `asyncio.get_event_loop()`, which didn't work. Returning Tornado's asyncio loop wrapper does the trick.

Comment: where do you put this piece of code? Can I just call tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop() anywhere in my test class, on each test?

Comment: Specifically exactly in the method shown above.

Comment: Thank you - the key for me to understand this was that this is overriding the method from AsyncTestCase (clearly commented but somehow I failed to see it at first!)